# Prove if the groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory

Prove if the groups are isomorphic.

The multiplicative group of all 2x2 matrices with determinant $1$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z})$

I have done questions similar to this, but struggle with this one, I don't really know where to start.

Thank you

Comment: What elements do the matrices have? i.e from $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: How many elements does $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb Z)$ have?

Comment: anything in Z?
My question says "the multiplicative group of all 2x2 matrices with determinant 1"
ad-bc=1

Comment: sym(z) has infinite elements?

Comment: @Emily There's infinite and there's infinite ...

Comment: it has less elements than Z

Comment: Hm, then I must be thinking of something dofferent. How is $\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb Z)$ defined in the first place?

Comment: That could be wrong, it probably is actually. Oh, Sym(Z) is the permutation group, on all n in Z, so actually it would have more elements than Z?

Comment: Yes. For $A\subseteq \mathbb N$ we have $x\mapsto \begin{cases}-x&\text{if }|x|\in A\\x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, which already gives us $|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)|=|\mathbb R|>|\mathbb Z|$ permutations.

Comment: an isomorphism has to preserve group structure, but does having a different amount of elements prove that there is not an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, because any group isomorphism is, in particular, a bijection of sets, which respects cardinality.

Comment: Would that be enough to prove it, so say that Sym(z) is larger than z?

Comment: I still don't see a clear indication of which matrix group we're talking about, i.e. from what ring we take matrix elements. If the group is $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$, then it is also has cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$, so that argument against isomorphism doesn't work.

Comment: 2x2 integer matrices of determinant 1

Comment: @Emily Then yes, it will be enough to prove that $|\operatorname{Sym}(\mathbb{Z})| > |\mathbb{Z}|$. The cardinality of your matrix group is $|\mathbb{Z}|$, so they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: would i have to prove that |Sym(ℤ)|>|ℤ|?

Comment: You could also try to prove that one of the groups has an element of order 5, and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

$(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ is in the symmetric group, and has order 5.

If a matrix $A$ has order 5, then $A^5=I$, and $A\ne I$. Then the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be a factor of $$x^5-1=(x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$$ This factor must have integer coefficients (since $A$ has integer entries) and degree at most 2 (since $A$ is $2\times2$. It's not hard to reach a contradiction from here.